# App is Running But Not Opening in Browser? It shows Page Not Available

Tags: node.js, express

In console it shows message that app/server is running but when I open app in browser it show page not available.

Here's my code for the server initialization (*app.js*):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var app = express();

var viewRoute = require('./routes/view'),
    apiRoute = require('./routes/api');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', viewRoute);
app.use('/api', apiRoute);

server.listen(9190, function(){
    var host = server.address().address,
    port = server.address().port;
console.log("Server Running @ http:%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

And my file with the routes (*api.js*):

```
var express = require('express');
var api = express.Router();

module.exports = (function() {
api.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("GET Request for Index Page");
});

api.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("GET Request for Home Page");
});

return api;
})();
```

I've already searched google and every other resources but can't find solution.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: http://localhost:9190/

Comment: No still it is not working

Comment: You need to initialize `app` before you initalize `server`, since now you're technically doing `var server = require('http').Server(undefined);`

Comment: Whilst off topic, it would seem far easier to use the express wrapper and simply call `app.listen`. But Bens answer is correct, its a simple hoisting issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not sending response back to browser,

in `api.js` change `api.get('/'` code to like following:

```
api.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Yes Its working now");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not sending anything back to the client, so nothing shows up in your browser. Use `res.send` or similar for this.

I'd suggest to change your code for something like this, and see if this works :

```
var express = require('express'),
        app = exports = module.exports = express();


app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    console.log("GET Request for Index Page");
    res.send("GET / - 200");
});
app.get('/home', function (req,res) {
    console.log("GET Request for home Page");
    res.send("GET /home - 200");
});
```

I removed the exported function immediate call by the way.

Answer (score -1):

I also had same issue, My server was running but i was not able to open my app on browser, Uninstalling **skype** worked for me.

Comment: skype may be using some port that was colliding with your node’s port.

Comment: Ya I know that, It was happening on all sort of ports, thats why choose to uninstall the skype